# Track Bugs as task on TFS 2012 project dashboard

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I follow this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920163(v=vs.110).aspx)

to add bugs to task board on TFS. It works.
But the problem is that the initial state of created bug is "Active", I want it to be in "New" State, so I modify the workflow according to "Task" workflow. When I go into the backlog, it give me a error message

> TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.

I googled but nothing useful. Is there anybody could help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the none existing state "Active" from CommonProcessConfig, so first export it:

```
witadmin exportcommonprocessconfig /collection:"CollectionURL" /p:MyProject /f:"DirectoryPath/CommonConfiguration.xml"
```

Remove the Active entry:

```
<TaskWorkItems category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task">
<States>
  <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
  <State value="Active" type="InProgress" /> <-- this one needs to be removed, if there is no "Active" state in Bugs or Tasks
  <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
  <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
</States>
```

Import the updated config file:

```
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:"CollectionURL" /p:MyProject /f:"DirectoryPath/CommonConfiguration.xml"
```